# Installing Visual Studio 2010 on a SharePoint "Farm"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Instlling a trial VS2010 on my workstation hoping to develop some simple custom web parts for our SharePoint 2010 webs. As soon as I try to create an appropriate projectd (Empty SharePoint project) I'm warned that VS2010 must be installed on the same server as SharePoint.

I can do this, but on which server... there are 5 of them on our farm. APP01, APP02, WFE01 (web front end), WFE02, and SQL.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't install Visual Studio on any of those servers. [Install SharePoint on your development computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28v=office.14%29.aspx), then once you develop your solutions deploy them to your test and finally production SharePoint servers as wsp files.